# Specify "Extra Light" font style in MATLAB figure `text` command

Tags: python, r, matlab, fonts, matlab-figure

I want to use `Gotham Cond SSm XLight` in MATLAB's `text` command to draw several digits, letters and symbols in the font above. However, it seems, according to [the official documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text-properties.html), `FontWeight` in `text` only allows `normal|bold`, but not `XLight` for Extra Light style.

Here is the fonts I have installed in my system.

```
$ ls GothamCondensed/OpenType/
GothamCondSSm-Black.otf        GothamCondSSm-Book.otf         GothamCondSSm-Medium.otf
GothamCondSSm-BlackItalic.otf  GothamCondSSm-BookItalic.otf   GothamCondSSm-MediumItalic.otf
GothamCondSSm-Bold.otf         GothamCondSSm-Light.otf        GothamCondSSm-XLight.otf
GothamCondSSm-BoldItalic.otf   GothamCondSSm-LightItalic.otf  GothamCondSSm-XLightItalic.otf
```

Here is what I used for MATLAB R2015b:

```
% draw symbol `$' in Gotham Cond SSm XLight
text(0,0,'$','FontName','Gotham Cond SSm','FontWeight', 'XLight');

% also try this, just in case
text(0,0,'$','FontName','Gotham Cond SSm XLight');
text(0,0,'$','FontName','Gotham Cond SSm XLight','FontWeight', 'XLight');
```

If it is not supported in MATLAB, even by some undocumented java hack, then it would still be great to be able to produce these symbols (e.g. `$') *in any language* (preferably Python or R) in high resolution by specifying size in pixels, then saving them as grayscale image files. I could then read those image files into my MATLAB struct.

Comment: That doesn't matter. If the font is a single font, not a family collection, then the "weight" attribute does nothing: one font has only one weight (unlike a collection, which as multiple fonts, each for different weights; then the weight attribute *does* do something). Just load the specific single font, done. It'll simply render text with the thickness that is has. It can't do any other weight.

Comment: Thanks! I tried using directly using font name `text(0,0,'$','FontName','Gotham Cond SSm XLight');` or font file name `text(0,0,'$','FontName','GothamCondSSm-XLight');`, but neither works.

Comment: Yeah, I just did a trawl of the internet I can find with web searching, and there is very little information about loading a font "from file". Will you be using the MatLab LaTeX engine?

Comment: I haven't modified the default engine, thus using its default engine (called `tex`). Matlab also has a `latex` engine, but I haven't tried that.

Comment: latex runs on top of tex, it's basically "a more human friendly API" built on top of the (extremely low level) TeX system, so going with latex tends to make things happen more, and easier. I've not used the (La)TeX engines in Matlab, but http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/297196 might be useful to you then.

Comment: I found that specifying an OpenType font `.otf` directly with exact file name (without the `.otf` extension) can enable that font in the default text rendering engine (`tex`). I am testing more on this, and if it fails, I will try out `latex` engine.